Caching files in parallel jobs only works in one of the jobs?
I have a Gitlab CI pipeline that runs 3 jobs in parallel and caches files created in those jobs to use further in the pipeline, but only files created in one of the 3 parallel jobs are actually being cached & available in subsequent jobs.
Here's basically what my pipline code looks like:
default:
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    paths:
      - release/**/*

stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2
  - stage3

job1:
  stage: stage1
  before_script:
    - mkdir release
  script:
    - echo 'job1' > release/job1

job2:
  stage: stage2
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ITEM:
          - item1
          - item2
          - item3
  script:
    - echo "job2-$ITEM" > release/job2-$ITEM

job3:
  stage: stage3
  script:
    - echo 'job3' > release/job3

post:
  stage: .post
  script:
    - ls release/

In the post job, the only file from stage2 is job2-item1. It should have also created job2-item2 and job2-item3.
In the item2 and item3 parallel jobs in stage2, it's creating those files and caching them but for some reason job3 isn't picking them up. also, the previously-cached items from job1 are being restored in job2 [item1] but not item2 or item3
job2 [item1]:
Successfully extracted cache
...
Creating cache 4e6ab4bcc8d3d0b12c60ee71276fd205ae555268-non_protected...
release/**/*: found 2 matching artifact files and directories 

Note that it says "found 2 matching artifact files"--the job1 file and the newly-created job2 [item1] file.
job2 [item2]:
WARNING: Cache file does not exist                 
Failed to extract cache
...
Creating cache 4e6ab4bcc8d3d0b12c60ee71276fd205ae555268-non_protected...
release/**/*: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 

Note that it only found 1 file--the newly-created job2 [item2] file, but it's not receiving the cached job1 file.
job2 [item3]:
WARNING: Cache file does not exist                 
Failed to extract cache
...
Creating cache 4e6ab4bcc8d3d0b12c60ee71276fd205ae555268-non_protected...
release/**/*: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 

What's the right way to accomplish this?

You should use artifacts instead of cache. Artifacts are designed to be shared between jobs
default:
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    paths:
      - release/**/*

stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2
  - stage3

job1:
  stage: stage1
  before_script:
    - mkdir release
  script:
    - echo 'job1' > release/job1
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - release/**/*

job2:
  stage: stage2
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - ITEM:
          - item1
          - item2
          - item3
  script:
    - echo "job2-$ITEM" > release/job2-$ITEM
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - release/**/*

job3:
  stage: stage3
  script:
    - echo 'job3' > release/job3
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - release/**/*

post:
  stage: .post
  script:
    - ls release/


these jobs will potentially have many GB of data so artifacts will take too long to upload/download and it'll explode the project storage
